# How do I print the growth rate for an exponential regression model?

Tags: r, regression, exponential

So, I created an exponential regression using 50 data points taken over 50 days.  Finding the summary of it resulted in the following:

```
> summary(TotalModel)

Call:
lm(formula = log(Total) ~ Time)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0570 -0.4827 -0.1168  0.5545  0.8195 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 4.537196   0.165779   27.37   <2e-16 ***
Time        0.148937   0.005658   26.32   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5773 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9352,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9339 
F-statistic: 692.9 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now, while this does provide me with some of the information I needed, I want to take the growth rate of this exponential model and print it to a variable that I will later export to a spreadsheet (and repeat this about 13 more times).  How do I get this value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your example above, the fitted model is:

```
log(Total) = 4.537196 + 0.148937 * Time
```

Exponentiating both sides, we have:

```
Total = exp(4.537196)*exp(0.148937 * Time)
```

Your growth rate is 0.148937 which is the coefficient of the `Time` variable. To extract this value, you could do

```
TotalModel$coefficients["Time"]
```

In general, in the future, if you're trying to see how you can extract a specific value from an object, a few things you can try include: (will not always work for every object but worth a try)

1. Look at the structure of your model by doing `str(TotalModel)`. In your case, you will see that one of the elements is `coefficients`, which you can access using `TotalModel$coefficients`
2. Type `TotalModel$` (with the dollar sign) and hit the tab key on your keyboard to see what possible elements can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

So a generic exponential function has the following form, where [image] is the exponential growth rate:

[image]

Looks like you have estimated the transformed log-linear model, ie:

[image]

Or, put another way, the OLS model you have estimated is:

[image]

where [image] and [image].

So then, the exponential growth rate is equal to:

[image]

You can calculate this from the `TotalModel` object, where `TotalModel$coefficient['Time']` is [image] and so, `r = exp(TotalModel$coefficient['Time']) - 1`.